# Python SMTP Email not reaching recipent

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I am trying to run a program that sends an email using smtplib in python 3.5 and it's not working. The email is being sent, and the recipient sees an email in their inbox, but it is empty (the message content is not there). The code looks a bit like this:

```
message = "Test Message"
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.live.com", 25)
server.starttls()
server.login("someone@hotmail.com", "someones_password")
server.sendmail("someone@hotmail.com", someone_else@somewhere.com, message)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use `server.ehlo()` before `server.starttls()`?

Like this:

```
message = "Test Message"
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.live.com", 25)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login("someone@hotmail.com", "someones_password")
server.sendmail("someone@hotmail.com", someone_else@somewhere.com,  message)
```